# Can someone explain these bridge stats?

Tags: bridge, pluggable-transports, obfs4

I have these stats:

```
# cat /var/lib/tor/stats/bridge-stats
bridge-stats-end 2015-02-13 04:17:28 (86400 s)
bridge-ips cn=8,es=8,us=8
bridge-ip-versions v4=8,v6=0
bridge-ip-transports <OR>=8,obfs4=8
```

I seems odd that the number 8 should be so consistently displayed. Have I really had 8 connections from each of China, Spain, and the US?  If so, why are there only 16 (8+8) shown on the transports line?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The lines have the following meaning:

```
bridge-stats-end 2015-02-13 04:17:28 (86400 s)
```

The time when the statistics have ended. They included 86400 seconds of data, which translates to a day.

```
bridge-ips cn=8,es=8,us=8
```

Your bridge had connections from China, Spain and the US. The number 8 basically tells you that there were only a low number of connections. It is the minimum number and your bridge attracts more connections it will always be a multiple of 8.

```
bridge-ip-versions v4=8,v6=0
```

All connections came over IPv4.

```
bridge-ip-transports <OR>=8,obfs4=8
```

Some of your bridge users used a pluggable transport (obfs4 in this case), while others just used your bridge. I'd guess that the chinese user(s) used obfs4, because normal bridges usually don't work in China and the other users might have used a plain bridge.